# deleting item from a mutableStateListOf it keeps the value of the deleted TextField passing this value to the other TextField below

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-text

deleting item from a `mutableStateListOf` it keeps the value of the deleted `TextField` passing this value to the other `TextField` below. I don't know if this is a error from Jetpack Compose.

This is a bit confusing since I deleted the first line right.

My code:

```
private var ids = mutableStateListOf<ShoppingCart>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent{
            i = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("produtos")!!
            ids=i.toMutableSet().toMutableStateList()

            ids = remember { ids }
                
            MainContent()
        }
    }

LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
    .padding(top = 50.dp)
    .weight(1f)
    .border(4.dp, colorResource(id = R.color.pastel_green))
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(ids) { index, item ->

            var quantidades by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = TextFieldValue.Saver) {
                mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(item.product_quant.toString()))
            }


            TextField(
                    value = quantidades,
                    onValueChange = {
                        quantidades = it

                        if (it.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                            item.product_quant = it.text.toInt()
                            calcular()
                        }
                    },
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                            disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent

                    ),
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(70.dp)
                        .height(70.dp)
                        .padding(top = 20.dp)

            )


            Button(
                    onClick = {
                        ids.removeAt(index)
                        
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 20.dp, end = 20.dp)
            ) {
                Icon(
                        Icons.Default.Delete,
                        stringResource(id = R.string.deletar)
                )
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want to achieve actually? Use one value for all the TextFields inside a single composable function?

Comment: I want that when deleting it doesn't change the value, keep the correct value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `items` of lazy view, it creates a scope depending on the `key`.

And when you pass no key, the default value is item index.

All `remember` values inside are bound to that key, so when you remove first cell, second one reuses it remember value, that's what happening in your case. You can pass some item `id` to prevent that.

But if you would have many items and would like to scroll your list, you'll see that these items are not gettings saved. You could've create a mutable state list, but it'll be cleaned during screen rotation.

I strongly recommend you out of storing state variables as global variables.

Instead of that, all data that should be shared and which you don't wanna loose should be inside a [view model](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state). It's gonna be shared in the whole composable tree, unless you're using compose navigation. For this case check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68857871/3585796) how you can share it.

As you need to modify `product_quant`, I suggest you making it a mutable state, so changes will trigger recomposition.

If you can't update `ShoppingCart`, you can create a `ShoppingCartState` wrapper, which will have a mutable state and update `ShoppingCart` value(if you need this):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val produtos = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("produtos")!!
    setContent{
        // initializing view model with produtos
        viewModel<ScreenViewModel>(
            factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
                override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>) =
                    ScreenViewModel(produtos) as T
            }
        )
        TestView()
    }
}
```

```
class ShoppingCartState(val shoppingCart: ShoppingCart) {
    private val _product_quant = mutableStateOf(shoppingCart.product_quant)
    var product_quant: Int
        get() = _product_quant.value
        set(value) {
            _product_quant.value = value
            shoppingCart.product_quant = value
        }
}

class ScreenViewModel(ids: List<ShoppingCart>) : ViewModel() {
    val shoppingCartStates = ids.map(::ShoppingCartState).toMutableStateList()

    fun calcular() {
        // do your calculations
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestView() {
    // you can pass view model as a parameter, but this also
    // will return same view model across whole composable tree
    val viewModel = viewModel<ScreenViewModel>()
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 50.dp)
            .border(4.dp, Color.Green)//colorResource(id = R.color.pastel_green))
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(viewModel.shoppingCartStates) { index, item ->
            Row {
                TextField(
                    value = item.product_quant.toString(),
                    onValueChange = {
                        if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                            item.product_quant = it.toInt()
                            viewModel.calcular()
                        }
                    },
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                        disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent

                    ),
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(70.dp)
                        .height(70.dp)
                        .padding(top = 20.dp)

                )


                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        viewModel.shoppingCartStates.removeAt(index)
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 20.dp, end = 20.dp)
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        Icons.Default.Delete,
                        "delete"
                        //stringResource(id = R.string.deletar)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback but I get the data from a webservice and my ShoppingCart class is a Parcelize

Comment: Thanks again but it still didn't work I will respond with my ShoppingCart class

Comment: @RafaelSouza could you explain how exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: I added new items in the states class and it worked thanks a lot

Comment: I found an error number 1 does not delete. It stays static

Comment: @RafaelSouza I don't understand. Is "error number 1" some field/variable of yours?

Comment: When TextField loads with value in case 1 it cannot erase the value of number 1

Comment: I changed _product_quant to string and it worked

Comment: Last question how to convert ShoppingCartState class to ShoppingCart class to pass between activities

Comment: @RafaelSouza `ShoppingCartState` has `ShoppingCart` as a variable: `shoppingCartState.shoppingCart`