# Other state management options that I may use with Jetpack Compose, beyond State hoisting?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am learning Jetpack compose, and I have been seen so far that lifting the state up to a composable's caller to make a composable stateless is the way to go. I`ve been using this pattern in my Compose apps.

For an app state that I need to modify from many different places of the tree, I will have to pass around a lot of callbacks, This can become difficult to manage.

I have some previous experience with Flutter. The way Flutter deals with providing a state to its descendants in the tree to overcome the above, is to use other mechanisms to manage state, namely Provider + ChangeNotifier.

Basically, with Provider, a Provider Widget is placed in the tree and all the children of the provider will have access to the values exposed by it.

Are there any other mechanisms to manage state in Jetpack Compose apps, besides State hoisting? And, what would you recommend?

Comment: Have you read about? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal

Comment: @M.RezaNasirloo No, I didn`t. I`m going to read it. Thanks

Comment: @M.RezaNasirloo is it really ok to use this for state? from my understanding google recommends to avoid using composition locals

Comment: I created my own state holder mechanism. It consist of a tree holding the Application  state. You can check it out here:
https://github.com/pablichjenkov/uistate3

Answer (score 3):

If you need to share some data between views you can use [view models](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state).

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen() {
    val viewModel = viewModel<SomeViewModel>()
    Column {
        Text("TestScreen text: ${viewModel.state}")
        OtherView()
    }
}

@Composable
fun OtherView() {
    val viewModel = viewModel<SomeViewModel>()
    Text("OtherScreen text: ${viewModel.state}")
}

class SomeViewModel(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel() {
    var state by savedStateHandle.saveable { mutableStateOf(UUID.randomUUID().toString()) }
}
```

The hierarchy topmost `viewModel` call creates a view model - in my case inside `TestScreen`. All children that call `viewModel` of the same class will get the same object. The exception to this is different destinations of Compose Navigation, see how to handle this case in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68857871/3585796).

You can update a mutable state property of view model, and it will be reflected on all views using that model. Check out more about [state in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state).

The view model lifecycle is bound to the compose navigation route (if there is one) or to `Activity` / `Fragment` otherwise, depending on where `setContent` was called from.

Comment: Taking the TestScreen composable of your example, as soon as you refactor the Column to a composable you have to pass the viewModel object, or its properties/methods as arguments. So as the tree of composables increase, I will have to pass around a lot of callbacks and properties of the viewModel.

Comment: @lbarqueira as you see I don't pass it into `OtherView`, but `viewModel()` will return the same object, because `OtherView` is child of `TestScreen`

Comment: May I conclude that the reason the Composable State codelab of Google when passing the viewmodel as composable function arguments is to satisfy the unidirectional data flow pattern, that is, state flows down and events flow up?

Comment: @lbarqueira could you give me a link of the code you're talking about?

Comment: Here it is: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#3

Comment: @lbarqueira I think this is to keep the example simple.  If you create a view model inside an activity with `viewModels()`, you can then get the same object in any composable with `viewModel()`(excluding compose navigation). Also, I made a mistake in my answer: `viewModel` will not be destroyed when the view disappears, its lifecycle is related to the `Activity` or `Fragment` calling `setContent` or to the current navigation route.