# Global ViewModel for app ui states in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to for example change the title of the appBar or whether the bottomNavBar should be shown in different composables. Since I don't want to pass that viewModel to every composable, I've created a viewModel called AppViewModel and inject it with Hilt to change these values, The mentioned viewModel is like this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AppViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {
    var showBottomNavBar = mutableStateOf(true)
}
```

In my main activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val appViewModel = hiltViewModel<AppViewModel>()
            val showBottomNavbar by remember {appViewModel.showBottomNavBar}
            AppTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                Scaffold(
                    bottomBar = {
                        if (showBottomNavbar)
                            BottomNavigation1(navController = navController)
                    }
                ) {
                    Box(Modifier.padding(it)) {
                        NavigationGraph(navController = navController)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in one of my destination composables like the one below If I change the `showBottomNavbar` it doesn't change anything.

```
@Composable
fun Product(
    navController: NavController,
    appViewModel: AppViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        appViewModel.showBottomNavBar.value = false
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve the what I'm looking for?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are not passing down the ViewModel, each composable with `appViewModel: AppViewModel = hiltViewModel()` would create a new `AppViewModel` if it is not passed.

Comment: @Abhimanyu https://stackoverflow.com/a/69221534/5097103 I read here that the top most call will create it and it is a singleton through out the app the rest of the calls will give the same object.

Comment: You've missed this part of the linked answer: "The exception to this is different destinations of Compose Navigation, see how to handle this case in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68857871/3585796)."

Comment: @PylypDukhov That doesn't help either if you have other viewmodels injected to composables if it keeps the same storeowner

Comment: You should be using SavedStateHandle in your AppViewModel, that's for sure.