# jetpack compose overlapping screens

Tags: android, navigation, dialog, jetpack

in Android jetpack compose
I must navigate to a screen with its view model and state.
I don't want to use dialog, because it makes my architecture complicated

so how to navigate from the first screen to the second screen, which overlaps on top of the first Screen, not replacing it?

this is what chatGPT gives me. but it is not working

```kotlin
@Composable
fun FirstScreen(navController: NavController) {
    Column {
        Text(text = "This is the first screen")
        Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("second") }) {
            Text(text = "Go to second screen")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SecondScreen(navController: NavController) {
    Dialog(onDismissRequest = { navController.popBackStack() }) {
        Text(text = "This is the second screen")
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "first") {
        composable("first") { FirstScreen(navController) }
        composable("second") { SecondScreen(navController) }
    }
}
```

Comment: overlap. you use viewmodel by coupling to the nav grpah instead of a compose screen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69642441/how-to-share-a-viewmodel-between-navgraph-components-only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `dialog` instead of `composable` in `NavHost`

this is the code in the current example

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "first") {
        composable("first") { FirstScreen(navController) }
        dialog("second") { SecondScreen(navController) }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FirstScreen(navController: NavController) {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Blue), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(text = "This is the first screen")
        Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("second") }) {
            Text(text = "Go to second screen")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SecondScreen(navController: NavController) {
    Column(Modifier.background(Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.1f))) {
        Text(text = "This is the second screen")
        Button(onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }) {
            Text(text = "Go back")
        }
    }
}
```