# Compose hiltViewModel returns a new instance

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I need the instance of activity ViewModel from a compose navigation screen, and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68943844/691626). In MainActivity, the ViewModel instance is obtained by

```
setContent {
    val viewModel = viewModel<MainViewModel>()
    MainScreen(
    ...
}
```

In NavHost

```
NavHost(navController, startDestination = "home") {
    composable(route = "home") {
        ....
    }
    navigation(startDestination = "myRoute", route = "Parent") {
        composable(route = "myRoute") { backStackEntry ->
            val parentEntry = remember(backStackEntry) {
                navController.getBackStackEntry("Parent")
            }
            val mainViewModel = hiltViewModel<MainViewModel>(parentEntry)
            MyScreen(navController, innerPadding, mainViewModel = mainViewModel)
        }
}
```

The problem is hiltViewModel creates a new instance of MainViewModel when navigating to MyScreen. I guess probably I misunderstood the solution because it might be for sharing the ViewModel between navigation screens only, if that's the case, how can I make it work?

Comment: Why are you creating a ViewModel at the activity level at all, if all you are going to do is access it in individual screens?

Comment: The MainViewModel does some initialization and provides data to be shared among screens, therefore, I need to interact with MainViewModel from individual screens. For example, in screen A I enter a database query, the same result will be available on screen B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of of all, you shouldn't use same view model in this way, that you described in the comments. For this situation, I would suggest you make some kind of `AppState` that will store the data that is needed on many screens. you can find an example [here](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Jetcaster/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetcaster/ui)

If you need share some small amount of data - you also can just put it to the arguments of the next screen

But if you realy think that you need to use same model on the multipole screens - look at the MainViewModel initialization. As I see you do it in the `setContent` scope. I think this is a source of issue. You can put some logging after this line to detect counts of recomposition. Most likely it is simply created several times due to recomposition.
So you need to move it outside of composition scope or use `remember`.

Also maybe change

```
val viewModel = viewModel<MainViewModel>()
```

to

```
val viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
```

Comment: Hi tasjapr, thank you very much for your input. I will try it and let you know how it works.

Comment: Hi tasjapr, I looked the sample project and thought Object Graph is the shared data you are referring to. Object is the singleton instance in Kotlin, it gave me the idea to check my Hilt setup and realized that my shared class was set correctly to be a singleton. After the fix, I am able to access the same data from different screens. Again, thank you very much for the help!!